# Getting Folder names instead of .mp3 files {Android}

Tags: java, android

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaylist() {
    File home=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
        Log.d(Variables.DEBUGTAG, "Filter Files=-->" + home.listFiles().length);
        for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
            song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
            song.put("songPath", file.getPath());
            Log.d(Variables.DEBUGTAG, "Reading Files");

            // Adding each song to SongList
            songsList.add(song);

        }
    }
    // return songs list array
    Log.d(Variables.DEBUGTAG, "Sending files to system");

    return songsList;

}

class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {

        return (filename.endsWith(".mp3") || filename.endsWith(".MP3"));
    }
}
```

While getting playlist it returns the folders or paths not the files from my external storage HELP....!!!
home.listFiles() array contains all the folders in emulated/0/sdcard in it..
right now the if block is false because no folder contains the .mp3 extension if i comment the if block and not using FileExtensionFilter then the for block contains folders only not any file....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only looking for files directly under the root folder of the external storage (`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`), so it makes sense there are no `mp3` files there. You should search the sub-folders of that directory recursively in order to find the `mp3` files.

Call `home.listFiles()` (without a filter), and for each directory, call `getPlayList()`. For that purpose you have to add a `File` argument to your `getPlayList` method. Each recursive call would return an `ArrayList` containing the details of all the `mp3` files its sub-folder tree contains.

For example :

```
public List<Map<String, String>> getPlaylist() {
    File home=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    return getPlaylist (home);
}

public List<Map<String, String>> getPlaylist(File root) {
    List<Map<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (root.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
        Log.d(Variables.DEBUGTAG, "Filter Files=-->" + home.listFiles().length);
        for (File file : root.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
            song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
            song.put("songPath", file.getPath());
            Log.d(Variables.DEBUGTAG, "Reading Files");

            // Adding each song to SongList
            songsList.add(song);

        }
    }
    for (File file : root.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isDirectory ()) {
            songsList.addAll(getPlaylist(file));
        }
    }

    return songsList;
}
```

Though it would probably be more efficient to do just one iteration of all the Files in the current directory. For sub-directories you'll make a recursive call and for files you'll check the file name to determine if it's an mp3 whose info should be added to the list.

Comment: @ArnoldBrown What's the difference? You can search for any filename filter you want.